# Identity Server3 Authentication for both Mobile and Web Application

Tags: authentication, jwt, identityserver3

I need to implement an authentication mechanism with JWT tokens for an mvc web application and a mobile application as well. Users will be able to register to our database and authenticate by using credentials (from signup) or use facebook single sign on. Both applications will use web API for data exchange with JWT token. I am thinking of using Identity Server 3 for that using Resource Owner Flow and i have some questions on that:

1) User will login from mobile application and will get a jwt token. Mobile application will verify it's validity and will refresh when needed. In order for mobile application to have user always logged in should i store refresh_token on device??? Is it secure?

2) I cannot understand how am i going to handle facebook authentication and get jwt token from identity server. Should i first get users email from facebook profile data and then what???

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You can store refresh token in database( identity server provide a token stor)
also you can use third party library to store tokens in device securely.

2-To use the 3rd party logins you need to do the redirect style to the IdSvr login page. Using resource owner password flow means you miss out on all the features in the token service like SSO, 2fa and federated authentication.

Comment: I understand your point, but i don't care as much for SSO and all other features. I think the most important think is to have a good User Experience without redirects.